# Why are non-leading variables in a linear system that corresponds to a matrix in row echelon form considered free?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having studied linear algebra in Russian, I was surprised to find out that non-leading variables in English are often referred to as independent or free, while leading variables are commonly called dependent. Let's say we have an underdetermined consistent linear system and its corresponding matrix A.
$$\begin{align}
& \begin{array}{llllll}
x_1 & + & 2x_2 & + & 3x_3 & = & 4 \\
\phantom{0x_1} & \phantom{+} & 3x_2 & + & 5x_3 & = & 3
\end{array} \\
&\nonumber \\
&\text{Let }A:= \left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 3 & 5 & 3
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}$$
Augmented matrix A is in row echelon form (allowing non-one leading coefficients), which means that $x_1$ and $x_2$ (which correspond to leading coefficients) are leading variables. Even though it is indeed convenient to present general solution to the system (with infinitely many solutions) using parametric equations parametrized over non-leading variables, do I understand correctly that it is rather a canonical choice of parameters, rather than one and only correct choice? For the given linear system, could the general solution be presented in the form of equations parametrized over any set of variables (in this case, any of $x_1$,$x_2$, $x_3$) or as it is often done only over non-leading variables (in this case, $x_3$)? As I perceive it, parametric equations in a sense merely define vector-valued functions whose image is the solution set for the system and there can be infinitely many such functions.

If the choice of parameters is arbitrary, what is the reason for other names for leading and non-leading variables, namely $``\text{dependent variables}"$ and $``\text{free variables}"$?

Similar question(s): [Why are free variables in systems of linear eqs used as parameter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124361/why-are-free-variables-in-systems-of-linear-eqs-used-as-parameter)

Comment: I think the only reason is that the free variables are, as indicated by the name, free. They may be chosen arbitrarily, and their choice will determine the dependent variables, which explains the name dependent variable. Some authors also use the termonology free and basic variables.

Comment: I've made the part about choice of parameters more explicit and developed my question to help you understand it better. By choice of parameters I meant not the choice of their values but rather the choice of variables for equations to be parametrized over.

Comment: In your example you could take either $x_2$ or $x_3$ as the "free" variable. So it is mostly just a "canonical" convenient choice. Not necessarily the only choice.